# Phonegap iOS 12 DisallowOverscroll not working

Tags: cordova, phonegap

I am unable to disable the scroll bounce on iOS 12. I have my config.xml setup so that DisallowOverscroll is to to true.

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-8.0.0" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

Comment: Did you get any solution so far ?

Comment: I did not. Unfortunately! I am still working on finding a solution. When I do find a solution, I will respond back.

Comment: @Matt Same problem here. In iOS13 too.